# What are Fidelity's equivalent ETFs of QQQ and SPY?

Tags: etf, fidelity

I am interested in purchasing QQQ and SPY but trying to find equivalent of those from Fidelity since there are some fees removed. I think SPY equivalent is Core S&P 500 (IVV) but not sure about SPY?

Comment: I don't thin there is one fidelity ETF for nasdaq100, QQQ seems the only one:http://etfdb.com/index/nasdaq-100-index/

Comment: What's wrong with .05% VOO for S&P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fidelity offers [free trading for iShares ETFs](https://www.fidelity.com/etfs/ishares).

If the motivation to this question is reduced cost then a better strategy would be to use a lower cost broker because the real ETF cost is not the cost to acquire so long as the acquisition is in bulk but the percentage of total investment lost each year to ETF fees.  Saving a trade fee instead of saving one percent of one's assets is a bad trade to me.

VOO for the S&P 500 and QQQ for the NASDAQ-100 would be the lowest cost alternatives.

Comment: +1 very good point about saving a trade fee vs saving in expense ratio.

Comment: @quantycuenta what's the best way/resource to access the ETF's lower cost alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

[ONEQ](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ONEQ) is the Fidelity ETF equivalent to QQQ. A fund [FUSEX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/315911206) follows S&P 500, but not closely (80% of the investment). IVV is sold as NTF by Fidelity (IVV and SPY are equivalents - IVV is from iShares, SPY is from SPDR).

Comment: Pretty big difference between QQQ and ONEQ; they track different indexes.   QQQ tracks the Nasdaq-100.  ONEQ tracks the Nasdaq Composite and has over 1000 components.

Answer (score 2):

itot is traded free at fidelity and is very close to spy.
xlk is like qqq but not free, oneq is

Comment: ITOT is not at all close to SPY.  ITOT has 3,352 components, mostly medium and small cap.  SPY has 507 components, all mega and large cap.